# Return to same tab after form submit

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using bootstrap tabs and when I submit a form from a tab, I want it to reload in the same tab. For that I tried using the # after the link and GET values I'm sending. The # shows up on the link when the form is submitted, but it doesn't set the tab active. Answers to questions on SO already asks to use ajax. But I do not want to use ajax for form submission.

```
<form action="store-admin.php?search=<?php echo $stname;?>#stock" method="post">
```

This is how my tabs are :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ophours">Open Hours</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#stock">Stock</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `<form action="store-admin.php?search=<?php echo $stname;?>&tab=stock" method="post">` at suggested by Matt Cowley and added this script after the unordered list is closed

```
<script>

var val = '<?php echo $_GET['tab'] ?>';
if(val != ''){
    //alert(val);   
    jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('a[href="#stock"]').tab('show');
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possibly make it 'a[href="#'+val+'"]' so that it can be any tab defined in the tab url var.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably add a url variable at the end, then detect it and write some jquery to activate the tab.

```
<form action="store-admin.php?search=<?php echo $stname;?>&tab=stock" method="post">
```

and in the page (probably should add more validation to the tab variable, but this is the basic):

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['tab'])) {
    echo "<script>$('.nav-tabs a[href=\"#".$_GET['tab']."\"]').tab('show');</script>";
} ?>
```

Comment: how can I set the `class="active"` for that tab using js?

Comment: <?php if (isset($_GET['tab'])) {
        echo "<script>$('.nav-tabs a[href=\"".$_GET['tab']."\"]').addClass('active');</script>";
    } ?>

Comment: I think I fixed my original answer.

Comment: nope, still nothing. I added more code to the question on how I've done the tabs